# There is any notation for a language that is empty infinite?

Tags: formal-languages, notation

Assume that $L$ is a language, is there any established notation that means that $L$ is infinite or empty?

Comment: For a language $L$, we generally say that $L=\varnothing$ or $L=\emptyset$ to mean $L$ is empty. There's no simple term I know of to indicate that $L$ is infinite, though you'll often see the informal expression $|\,L\,|=\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way to describe these properties is by indicating the size of $L$, denoted by $|L|$.

- Empty language, the size is zero, $|L|=0$
- Finite language, $|L|=c$ or in general, the size in non-infinite, $|L|< \infty$
- Infinite language, $|L|=\infty$.

Comment: To summarize, the statement in the question can be written as $|L| \in \{0, \infty\}$ or $|L| \not\in \mathbb{N}$ (assuming $0 \not\in \mathbb{N}$). Nitpick note: we usually say *cardinality* instead of "size" when sets are concerned.